# Extracting Value From A String in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, string, split

```
public static string GetMacQ(string rawValues)
    {
        return rawValues.Split('#')
        .Select(element =>
        {
            var value = element.Split('='); 
            return new 
            {
                Key = value[0],
                Value = value[1],
            };
        })
        .Where(element => element.Key.Equals("Mac Q")) 
        .Select(element => element.Value) 
        .FirstOrDefault();  
    }
```

This code is for splitting the strings, but the problem here is it does not return the value of the key

Comment: use `String.Split`. It will create Array/List for you and separate string by given separator,in your example separator is: `[##]` and result of split would look like: `array[0]='C=True'`, `array[1]='V=True'`, `array[2]='PAN=True'`, `array[3]='Mac Q=3'` etc... then you can use split again with the `=` separator to get key and value.

Comment: do you have the example of the coding for this ? thanks in advance cause im new to C# so i dont know how to do this in coding forms

Comment: Why did you [delete your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672194/extract-value-c-sharp) on your other account and then repost it? Your question was closed for lacking details - why did you post it again verbatim without addressing the concerns raised by Jon Skeet and Franz Gleichmann?

Comment: @Shelby answer is already posted below.

Comment: welcome **again** to stackoverflow. i **really** recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). they teach you not just how this platform works, but how to formulate a good question - which, usually, is at least half the work of solving a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq

You can **check/run** this code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/pYtUUl

## Full example code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace License
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static string GetValue(string key, string rawValues)
        {

            return rawValues.Split("[##]") // Split the string with [##] separator. e.g. ["C=True", "V=True", "PAN=True", "Mac Q=3", "A=True"];
            .Select(element => //Using the extension function SelectWhere declared above.
            {
                var value = element.Split("="); //Split the string with = separator. e.g. / ["C", "True"] / ["PAN", "True"] / ["Mac Q", "3"]
                return new //Creating new anonymous object with Key and Value properties. e.g { Key : "Mac Q", Value: "3"}
                {
                    Key = value[0].Trim(),
                    Value = value.Length < 2 ? string.Empty : value[1] //Check if element has 2 elements after split. if length < 2 value is empty string.
                };
            })
            .Where(element => element.Key.Equals(key)) //Filter elements with key value
            .Select(element => element.Value) //Select the value
            .FirstOrDefault();  //Get the first ocurrence or null.
        }

    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string key = "Mac Q";

            string rawValues = "C=True[##]V=True[##]PAN=True[##]Mac Q[##]A=True"; //Mac Q is empty
            string value = Utils.GetValue(key, rawValues); //Calling to the function
            Console.WriteLine(value == null ? $@"""{key}"" value not found." : $@"Mac Q value is ""{value}""");

            rawValues = "C=True[##]V=True[##]PAN=True[##]A=True"; //Mac Q is not present.
            value = Utils.GetValue(key, rawValues); 
            Console.WriteLine(value == null ? $@"""{key}"" value not found." : $@"Mac Q value is ""{value}""");

            rawValues = "C=True[##]V=True[##]PAN=True[##]Mac Q=3[##]A=True"; //Mac Q is present with value
            value = Utils.GetValue(key, rawValues); 
            Console.WriteLine(value == null ? $@"""{key}"" value not found." : $@"Mac Q value is ""{value}""");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Mac Q value is ""
"Mac Q" value not found.
Mac Q value is "3"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort i will try this

Comment: {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}

Comment: @Shelby I already improved the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
// The string to be parsed.As can be seen in the string, this is some key/value pairs, which are separated by [##]
var subkey = "C=True[##]V=True[##]PAN=True[##]Mac Q=3[##]A=True";

// Here we split the string by the separator [##]
var pairs = subkey.Split("[##]");

// Now let's create a storage to store the key/values
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    // The keys and values are separated by "=". So we split them by the separator.
    var split = pair.Split("=");
    // Now let's add the to the storage
    dic.Add(split[0], split[1]);
}

// OK. done. Let's verify the result.
foreach(var item in dic)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}={item.Value}");
}
```

Comment: I am not the person who downvoted, but I think the problem is, that you don't explain your code. So it is hard for other people to understand **why** this code works. So please add an explanation

Comment: i dont know why someone downvoted you, this solution is correct but might be dangerous. If they key's (in string) would contain duplicates, it would cause an exception of duplicated key.

Comment: Ok. I will add description to mu code

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort i will try this too